# Making DataArray return a float by default instead of a 0-dimensional array

Tags: numpy, python-xarray

Consider the following example below using DataArray:

```
In [34]: import xarray as xr

In [35]: da=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(5,5,5), dims=['x', 'y', 'z'], coords=dict(x=range(5), y=range(5), z=range(5)))

In [36]: da.mean()
Out[36]: 
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(0.547996)
```

The type of the returned object from the mean operation is actually a DataArray without any dimensions. However, sometimes this is cumbersome and I'd like `xarray` to return a good ol' float at those times. Is this possible? Ideally there would be something like `xr.options.return_mode' or something like that (instead of having to use an extra argument in every function).

Comment: `da.mean()[0]`?

Comment: @StephenRauch, `[0]` won't work on a 0d array, at least not in `numpy`.  I assume `xarray` behaves the same.  Extracting elements from 0d requires `.item()` or `[()]` indexing.

Comment: @hpaulj `da.mean()[()]` still returns a DataArray, but `da.mean().item()` works (silly but I hadn't thought of it). If nothing better comes along, consider writing an answer with that so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5):

At present, xarray doesn't have anything like `xr.options.return_mode`. From the xarray [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-don-t-aggregations-return-python-scalars):

> xarray tries hard to be self-consistent: operations on a DataArray
>   (resp. Dataset) return another DataArray (resp. Dataset) object. In
>   particular, operations returning scalar values (e.g. indexing or
>   aggregations like mean or sum applied to all axes) will also return
>   xarray objects.
>
> Unfortunately, this means we sometimes have to explicitly cast our results from xarray when using them in other libraries.

So either of these should work if you want a python scalar:

```
float(da.mean())
```

or

```
da.mean().item()
```