# 0-dimension ndarray created with xarray and enumerate: bug or feature?

Tags: numpy-ndarray, python-xarray

Please find below a minimum example of how I iterate through time in xarray.

```
ds = xr.Dataset({'time': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=8)})
for ii, date in enumerate(ds.time):
    nd = date.data
```

`nd` is a `numpy.ndarray` but of size = 1; no shape: shape = `()` and 0-dimension: dims = 0.
I can access the element through `nd[()]` (it took me a while, thx Clive), but I wonder if it is something we should expect or if it is a bug.

If there is a better way to enumerate through my date, please let me know or point me out where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The `nd` array as a 0d array is a feature; explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49621796/3064736.

There is a small bug given a recent pandas change such that `nd.item()` returns an int rather than a date on the most recent versions of xarray & pandas. That's being tracked here: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/4292.

Generally we would want `nd=data.item()`